# Interpreting timing results from timingSamps option in R caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using R caret package to compare the performance
of different classifiers on my data.

One way I want to quantify the performance is to be
able to say something about the time
taken to classify an observation by each classifier
relative to the other classifiers.

I think the information given by setting the timingSamps option in 
trainControl will allow me to get the information I need.
I don't know how to interpret it though and the documentation is fairly opaque as to what is actually being measured.

relevant code bits:

```
control <- trainControl(..., timingSamps=20)
model <- train(..., trControl=control)
model$timings
```

The output is:

```
> model$times
$everything
   user  system elapsed 
800.774   2.713 804.273 

$final
   user  system elapsed 
3.323   0.007   3.335 

$prediction
   user  system elapsed 
0.017   0.000   0.016
```

**How do I interpret prediction time?**
a) Time to predict a single observation
b) Time to predict a set of observations
c) something else entirely

The documentation has this to say:

> timingSamps the number of training set samples that will be used to measure the time for predicting
>   samples (zero indicates that the prediction time should not be estimated.

But that doesn't tell me how to interpret the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the source-code of the `train` function suggests that it is the time taken to predict the number of samples you specified in `trainControl`

Relevant source code (from: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R)

```
if(trControl$timingSamps > 0) {
pData <- x[sample(1:nrow(x), trControl$timingSamps, replace = TRUE),,drop = FALSE]
out$times$prediction <- system.time(predict(out, pData))
} else  out$times$prediction <- rep(NA, 3)
out
```